# Create an ArrayList that can hold String objects

Tags: java, arrays, object, arraylist

... add the names of 3 cars to the arraylist and then display the contents of the arraylist..

This is for a question in my class, my last one. 
Please help

Comment: Please show your efforts first.. Provide tried code! This is not the place to get the ready made code for your needs!

Comment: [How to ask about homework](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10811/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions). Make a good faith attempt to solve the problem yourself first. Ask about *specific* problems with your *existing* implementation. Admit that the question is homework. Be aware of school policy regarding outside help. Never use code you don't understand.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need full code:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class ArrayList_Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ArrayList<String> carNames = new ArrayList<String>(3);
        carNames.add("carName1");
        carNames.add("carName2");
        carNames.add("carName3");
        for (String carName : carNames) {
            System.out.println(carName);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: No downvote, but I would suggest `List<String> carNames = new ArrayList<>()`. It is better to suggest programming to interfaces than the specific implementing class.

Comment: @KevinO, I thought it would be harder to explain for Suyash